# dconf editor value is different from gsettings get value

Tags: linux, gnome, screen-lock, dconf, gsettings

I did as follows:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay
uint32 300

$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 80

$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay
uint32 80
```

But when I do: `dconf dump /org/gnome/`, I see as follows:

```bsh
$ dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/session
[/]
idle-delay=uint32 60
```

**Observation**: `dconf dump` shows real value, but `gsettings` shows new value but it is different from the one shown by dconf-editor

## After Restarting

```bsh
$ dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/session
[/]
idle-delay=uint32 60

$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay
uint32 300
```

**Observation**: `dconf dump` shows real value, but `gsettings` shows default value

---

Does this mean that `gsettings` are not working on my system? If so, how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you see any changes done to `dconf` when running `gsetting`? Use: `dconf watch /org/gnome/ idle-delay`

Comment: @slybloty I ran `dconf watch /org/gnome/ idle-delay` in first terminal. And I used `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 80` in another terminal. Nothing happened on the first terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem with gsettings not being able to change the desktop background. Then I found this [link](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/gsettings-not-working-to-change-wallpaper/13867/14) showing that the anaconda installation changes the path from the original gsettings:

```
$ which gsettings
/home/rafael/.anaconda3/bin/gsettings
```

So I moved `~/.anaconda3/bin/gsettings` to `~/.anaconda3/bin/gsettings_bkp`, and now the original gsettings is being used:

```
$ which gsettings
/usr/bin/gsettings
```