# Gnome does not respect text-scaling-factor value set by gsettings command

Tags: gnome, udev, manjaro, gsettings

I switched to Manjaro 20.2 GNOME and I am facing a issue when trying to run a script on external monitor connect/disconnect event in udev. In popos this script was working fine, and it seems like the udev triggering is working, but the `gsettings` command is not working.

The issue is the following - when running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.14` in PopOS (previous distro) the accessibility option in the top bar is shown and it instantly scales the text as it should. In Manjaro it does nothing. When i check for the value with `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor` it returns `1.13999` but the changes do not reflect in UI or when looking in `dconf-editor`, which still show `1.0`.

In addition, when changing the value in `tweak-tools` or in `dconf-editor`, the UI instatnly scales accordingly but when re-toggling the scaling using the slider in the top panel menu, then it resets to `1.25` not `1.14` as I've set it before or as `gsettings get` returns. To make it clear, after retoggling the "Large text" `dconf-editor` shows the value to be `1.25` but `gsettings get` still shows `1.13999`.

Though it is somewhat irrelevant to the issue by now, here is the script which uses the dbus socket to run `gsettings`:

```
# rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/text_scale.rules:
# SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/home/user/.bin/scale_text"

# Need to run 'gsettings' as user, so lets get the user id
# Get the Real Username
RUID=$(who | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}')

# Translate Real Username to Real User ID
RUSER_UID="$(id -u ${RUID})"

# Get the current text-scaling-factor
CURRENT_FACTOR=$(sudo -u ${RUID} \
  DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/${RUSER_UID}/bus" \
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor)

if (( $(echo "$CURRENT_FACTOR == 1.0" | bc -l) ))
then
  sudo -u ${RUID} DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/${RUSER_UID}/bus" \
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.14
else
  sudo -u ${RUID} DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/${RUSER_UID}/bus" \
    gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

So I stumbled on an similar issue [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570053/dconf-editor-value-is-different-from-gsettings-get-value?rq=1) and ran `which gsettings`, which returned surprisingly `/home/user/miniconda3/bin/gsettings` (why even have it in conda, is it for some python gtk development reason?).

So I renamed that folder and now everything works, because the gsettings binary falled back to the `/usr/bin/gsettings` as it should've been all along.